# It is possible to index a Map in spring data mongodb? It is possible to use a Map<A,B> where a A,B are 2 documents?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

```
class A { 

  @TextIndexed
  private Map<String,String> description;

}
```

It is possible to use @TextIndexed in a map? I want to index all the values in the map.

Instead if i use

```
class V { 

  private Map<A,B> description;

}
```

can I use this form where A, B are documented?

Comment: MongoDB cannot index "keys" and `Map` will be converted to basic `key/value` form when storing as BSON ( in fact anything other than `String` in the key is not allowed ). The other problem with a `Map` is that MongoDB needs to know the "path" to index on. So you cannot create an index on what is essentially an "undefined' or "variable" name of the path. So logically, NO.

Comment: In my case i need just mondgodb tokenized map rappresended in js form . If i use JSONObject instead a map? is the same?

Comment: Same deal. In simply JSON notation as an example. `"field": { "a": 1, "b": 2 }` We can create an index on the path `"field.a"` without problem. If however you create an index on `"field"` alone ( which is what you are asking, even if you don't realize it ) then it actually does nothing and never stores any value in the index unless a document happens to have `"field": 1` with a valid value at that path. The path to simply `{}` is effectively `null`.

Comment: Note that because MongoDB :"itself" is "schemaless", nothing actually stops you from creating the index. MongoDB cannot "presume" what is present in any document. So if you specify an index path that does not exist in any document, the index basically sits around waiting for something valid to appear within the specified path.

Comment: Ok another solution is to use a external class Description { TextIndexed content , DBRef Object objReference} but it is possible to use DBRef over a generic Object?

Comment: Well the general "idea" is that you really should be using a Class here and not just a `Map`. Whatever you do though **don't use `DBRef`**. Horrible idea in the first place and basically not supported in any modern MongoDB features. Still surprised it has not been officially deprecated.

Comment: In spring data mongodb there is no other options searching in the manual for dbref :(

Answer (score 1):

Since mongodb's [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#overview) state that the text indexes (created by spring data mongodb's `@TextIndexed`) can only be used for fields whose values are strings or an array of strings, a way to approach solving this problem can be to specify another String field in your class to store a whitespace delimited string of the values of the map and annotate that field with `@TextIndexed`.

So for `class A`:

```
class A { 

  private Map<String, String> description;
  @TextIndexed private String descriptionVals;

  public A(Map<String, String> description) {
    this.description = description;
    this.descriptionVals = String.join(" ", description.values());
  }

}
```

For `class V`, assuming `B` has a reasonable `toString()` method, the following code can be used:

```
class V { 

  private Map<A,B> description;
  @TextIndexed private String descriptionVals;

  public V(Map<String, String> description) {
    this.description = description;
    this.descriptionVals = description.values().stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
  }
}
```

With this, if searching is the goal, the `TextCriteria` class can be used with a `List<V> findAllBy(TextCriteria criteria)` MongoRepository query method this way:

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matching("search text");
```